# Non-EU family member travelling with EU national!

Tags: eu-citizens, family

I'm an EU national, my mother in law who is non-EU national  is waiting for the residency permit as an EU national family member, she had 90 days tourist visa type C which is already expired, my question is can she travel with me to another EU member state while while still waiting for her residency permit as an EU national family member?

Comment: This has been [asked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/93219/19400) and [answered](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/93222/19400) on [travel.SE].

Comment: My close vote: as phoog points out, the [same question/same user/same day on TSE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93219/what-are-the-rules-for-a-non-eu-family-member-travelling-with-an-eu-national) and was fully responded to by phoog within less than 2 hours.